# Split-screen scrolling site not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, split

i'm trying to recreate an effect i saw online: [example](http://www.puma.com/actvrcvr/#/home). So there are two columns one scrolling up and one scrolling down. see image:

[image: example image]

Now i'm not the best coder but i've come up with this:

```
var update = function () {
    $('.right').height($(window).height());
    $('.right .content').height($(window).height() * 5);
    $('.left .content').height($(window).height() * 5);
    $('.col, .content').width($(window).width() / 2);
    $('.right').scrollTop((
    $('.right .content').height() - $(window).height()) * (
    1 - $(window).scrollTop() / ($('.left .content').height() - $(window).height())));
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    update();
});
$(window).scroll(function () {
    update();
});
$(window).resize(function () {
    update();
});
```

See [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u9apC/), and it seems to be working but if i try adding 100 percent divs to each side, it stops working for some weird reason. The right side just doesn't scroll anymore if i add these divs..

Can anyone figure out what is wrong? Or does anyone have a better example of how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post not working jsfiddle example? I set 100% width to divs and everything is fine

Comment: There's a plugin which creates a similar effect but with an automatic scroll instead of the normal one: [multiscroll.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/multiScroll/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created a revised version which allows separate *pages* instead of two long columns, I think from your description that this should meet your needs:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u9apC/2/)

HTML

```
<div class="body">
    <div class="col left">
        <div class="content">1</div>
        <div class="content">2</div>
        <div class="content">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col right">
        <div class="content">1</div>
        <div class="content">2</div>
        <div class="content">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
.body {
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
.col
{
    height:100%;
    width:50%;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0;
}
.content
{
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
}
.col.left .content:nth-child(odd) {
   background:steelblue;
}
.col.left .content:nth-child(even) {
   background:blue;
}
.col.right .content:nth-child(odd) {
   background:pink;    
}
.col.right .content:nth-child(even) {
   background:red;    
}
.col.right
{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
```

JS

```
(function ($) {
    var top = 0;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var contentHeight = $('.right').height(),
            contents = $('.right > .content').length;

        top = (0 - (contentHeight * (contents - 1)));

        $('.right').css('top', top + 'px');
    });

    $(window).resize(function () {
        var contentHeight = $('.right').height(),
            contents = $('.right > .content').length;

        top = (0 - (contentHeight * (contents - 1)));

        $('.right').css('top', (top + $(window).scrollTop()) + 'px');
    });

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        $('.right').css('top', (top + $(window).scrollTop()) + 'px');
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks mate! this is what i was going for